# RealityKit - mixing EntityTranslationGestureRecognizer and UIPanGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, realitykit

It is possible to have both EntityTranslationGestureRecognizer and UIPanGestureRecognizer on the same entity?

Once I install EntityTranslationGestureRecognizer on an entity, the UIPanGestureRecognizer will no longer work on that Model Entity (with Collisions set up).

It seems that the usual APIs for managing multiple gestures in view, such as the delegate to determine whether two gesture recognizers should simultaneously recognize a gesture `func gestureRecognizer(UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool` does not work with EntityTranslationGestureRecognizer.

Thank you.